# 〒 symbol in a resume

Tags: symbols

I have a doubt concerning the symbol 〒. What does it mean when in a resume it's followed by a number? e.g: 〒 331-0811

Comment: Did you try [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%80%92)?

Comment: 埼玉県 さいたま市北区 吉野町

Answer (score 7):

〒 is the symbol for Postal Code. In japan it has 7 digits (the number you see after it).